# is.na and quantile with sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am using `sparklyr` and it seems to be working well. However, some of my former code will not be implemented.

When is use

```
complete.cases
```

I get

> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function
>   COMPLETE.CASES

I get the same result for the `quantile` function

Furthermore is seems that in Spark dataframes the `is.na` is not computed the same way. So when I do

```
filter(!is.na(V1) & is.na(V2))
```

I get an empty dataframe instead of it returning all fields that are full in `V1` and empty in `V2`.

Any advice how these functions can be used/modified for `sparklyr`, or how wrappers for these can be constructed?

Comment: Maybe you want `filter(!is.na(V1) & !is.na(V2))`? The `!` will take precedence over the `&` as you have it, giving rows where `V1` is not missing and `V2` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na.omit` as in:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
tbl_flights <- copy_to(sc, flights)

tbl_flights %>% na.omit
```